# I have to expose the service to a load balancer?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-helm

i'm doing a little exercise to pratice the [epinio.io](https://epinio.io) framework inside a local k8s cluster, but when i get to do a deploy of a sample application, it gives me the error 503, can someone help me to see what am i doing wrong?

I'm suspecting that the helm chart is creating a service of type cluster ip, but in that case i think i needed to attach the nginx ingress controller in order for the service to work.

This is the repo that i'm trying to build it locally [naneko-devexp](https://gitlab.com/devprodexp/nameko-devexp)

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    epinio.io/created-by: admin
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: nameko-0426a4327bc264b3df3a0d0d2e4b42c068a659dc
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: workspace
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: websecure
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2023-11-17T04:04:10Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: application
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: nameko
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: workspace
    helm.sh/chart: epinio-application-0.1.26
  name: rnameko-0426a4327bc264b3df3a0d0d2e4b42c068a659dc
  namespace: workspace
  resourceVersion: "60430"
  uid: 2686c4f0-90e6-4f78-bf5e-bafecda65294
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.98.164.111
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.98.164.111
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: application
    app.kubernetes.io/name: nameko
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```